# Not able to list the namesapce

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

i am new to python and Kubernetes, i have installed the Kubernetes client, i was trying to get the namespace below is my code:

```
 from kubernetes import client, config
 def main():

    config.load_kube_config()
    k8s_apps_v1 = client.AppsV1Api()
    resp = k8s_apps_v1.list_namespaced_deployment(
        namespace="some name")
    print(resp)


 if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but i am getting the below error :

---

/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /Users/some name/PycharmProjects/some name/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
`enter code here`File "/Users/some name/PycharmProjects/some name/main.py", line 1, in 
from kubernetes import client, config
File "/Users/some name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/kubernete/**init**.py", line 19, in 
import kubernetes.client
File "/Users/some name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/kubernetes/client/**init**.py", line 20, in 
from kubernetes.client.api.well_known_api import WellKnownApi
File "/Users/some name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/**init**.py", line 6, in 
from kubernetes.client.api.well_known_api import WellKnownApi
File "/Users/some name/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/well_known_api.py", line 18, in 
import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'

Process finished with exit code 1

---

Here is my init file

```
    # limitations under the License.
    
    __project__ = 'kubernetes'
    # The version is auto-updated. Please do not edit.
    __version__ = "25.0.0-snapshot"
    
    import kubernetes.client
    import kubernetes.config
    import kubernetes.dynamic
    import kubernetes.watch
    import kubernetes.stream
    import kubernetes.utils
    import kubernetes.leaderelection
```

Comment: I am using Pycharm IDE

Comment: It seems that you made something false with the installation of the kubernetes package. The package kubernetes has six as a dependency. Did you install it using pip ?

Comment: @Zackorrigan Yes i installed it. I tried again and i got this - Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Comment: Is it possible that site-packages directory is only writable by root and if you're using pycharm to install packages it tries to install them as the current user and cannot write them ?

Comment: @Zackorrigan you are correct, the path for six was different then other kubernetes module i copied and pasted all the module at same place